# How to trigger an image to move when users scroll the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Is there any way to make an image move up when users scroll the page? I have 2 square images (each 400px in wide and height), both are visible. The left image is fixed by position. The right image is positioned 200px below the left image. I need to make the right image to move up by 200px (get aligned with the left image) when we scroll the page. Then the it stays still on that position.

I found the one on this page is quite the same with what I'm trying to create http://jessandruss.us/#waiting The difference is my images are all visible, while on this page the overflow of the left image is hidden and it gets back to its original position when users scroll up.

Really appreciate any help on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: could you share the code you have so far ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must **include the shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You may try something like that : https://jsfiddle.net/xfp34c0o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var aligned = false; // A flag to tell us when the images are aligned
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if($(this).scrollTop() == 192 ) { // when the window scroll to the alignment point... 
        aligned = true; // the images are aligned
    }
    if (aligned) { // if they're aligned... 
        $(".image-2").css("top", 8 + $(this).scrollTop()) // match .image-2's top css property
    }                                                   // to the window's scrollTop value, +
                                                        // 8px for the body's margin.  
  })
})
```

[Here's a JSFiddle with what I think you want.](https://jsfiddle.net/k5fmhgjw/4/)

There's simply a boolean to tell us when the images are lined up. When they are, image-2's CSS property 'top' is matched to the window's scrollTop value.

The boolean variable is currently hard coded to tell us when the images are lined up (I looked at the window's scrollTop value when they were lined up, 192 in this case). This isn't a great approach since it won't account for changes in the images' positions or sizes, but this should be enough to get to going.

**EDIT**

https://jsfiddle.net/eLdo0s3w/5/

Here's another method to achieve the same result. As long as having the second image `position: fixed` is OK, then it should be more efficient, and will hopefully avoid the jumping around that OP says happened with the first method.

It targets image-2's `top` CSS property and matches it to the window.scrollTop value, until image-2 reaches the necessary point.

Again, this code isn't very reusable, but it should work fine for a one-off situation. If anyone wants improve on it, please do so!

Comment: I just noticed that if you scroll quickly it's possible to scroll image-2 above image-1. Just change `==` to `>=` in the line `if($(this).scrollTop() == 192 ) {` for an easy fix.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you. I just realized when the images are aligned, they get a little shaky. Is it because the fast scrolling? I'm wondering if you could help for the smooth transitions? Would really2x appreciate if you'd like to help. Thank you :)

Comment: I've just edited my first answer. As long as you're OK with image-2 having position: fixed, then this should solve your shaky issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use jQuery to link the picture's transform: translateY() property with scrollTop(). It's a little hard to explain in words, but if you provide a jsfiddle I'll show you what I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure what to use. What I currently have looks like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/b1L0erL6/4/). I think I have to useinview jQuery to achieve this, but it still not working. Would really appreciate your help. Thanks very much.